Pipewire combine-stream not outputting to slaves
My Debian testing is running pipewire and pipewire-pulse to output audio to headphones and speakers using the combine-sink module. This has worked fine for a long while and suddenly yesterday stopped working (neither the headphones nor the speakers output any audio when playing audio to the combined sink).
Apt logs shows pipewire was updated to 1.2.5-1 ten days ago, and the machine has rebooted since and it was still working as expected, so this doesn't look like an update to pipewire or pipewire-pulse. I have no idea what might have changed : the machine did not reboot between the working and not-working state, and restarting it after it stopped working didn't help. I couldn't find any trace of something happening to pipewire or pulse around that time in the journal, nor any clue as to what might be wrong.
I've narrowed down the problem to the combine-sink module not outputting to the slaves in the following way :

If I move an app playing audio to the headphones sink, audio plays there
If I move an app playing audio to the speakers sink, audio plays there
If I move an app playing audio to the combined sink, no audio plays on either device. However pavucontrol shows the combine sink has activity, and no activity on either of the physical devices.

Here is what pavucontrol thinks of my setup when playing some audio to the combined sink :

In this screenshot the combined sink is called All, the headphones Casque and the speakers Enceintes. Observe how there is activity playing on All but not on etiher of the other outputs.
Here is what Helvum thinks of my setup (irrevelant stuff like input devices moved to the left of the screenshot) :

Helvum's output looks to me like the All sink should play audio on both Casque and Enceintes.
Here is the description of the pipewire object associated with the combined sink, as output by pw-cli info :
        id: 30
        permissions: r--m-
        type: PipeWire:Interface:Module/3
        name: "libpipewire-module-combine-stream"
        filename: "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pipewire-0.3/libpipewire-module-combine-stream.so"
        args: "{
      combine.mode = sink
      node.name = "All"
      node.description = "All"
      combine.latency-compensate = false
      combine.props = {
        audio.position = [ FL FR ]
      }
      stream.props = {
      }
      stream.rules = [
        {
          matches = [
          {
            media.class = "Audio/Sink"
            node.nick = "~Enceintes|Casque"
          }
          ]
          actions = {
            create-stream = {
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }"
*       properties:
*               module.name = "libpipewire-module-combine-stream"
*               object.id = "30"
*               object.serial = "30"
*               module.author = "Wim Taymans <wim.taymans@gmail.com>"
*               module.description = "Combine multiple streams into a single stream"
*               module.usage = "( node.latency=<latency as fraction> ) ( combine.mode=<mode of stream, playback|capture|sink|source>, default:sink ) ( node.name=<name of the stream> ) ( node.description=<description of the stream> ) ( audio.channels=<number of channels, default:2> ) ( audio.position=<channel map, default:[ FL FR ]> ) ( combine.props=<properties> ) ( stream.props=<properties> ) ( stream.rules=<properties> ) "
*               module.version = "1.2.5"

I've tried restarting pipewire, removing my setup that creates the combined sink and adding it manually (both using pw-cli and pactl), but all my attempts have resulted in the same state, where the combined sink is apparently playing audio but neither physical device (or either of the associated sinks) do.
I don't know what else to do to investigate what is wrong. How do I investigate further ?

Okay so after 6 weeks of being annoyed and even compiling my own pipewire to add some debug prints, things suddenly started working again with no reason that I could understand... at first.
The reason there was no sound is that the combined sink actually creates a virtual stream for each of its outputs (it's visible in the Halvum screenshot with the name "All output", but I had no way to know it was a stream and no app or widget would show that stream), and it turns out that these streams had their volume set to zero. I don't know how the volume came to be set to 0, but sure enough, turning it up again fixes the issue and I can repro by turning it down again.
The way I noticed was by mistakenly installing kmix. Having been using KDE forever I thought the plasma volume widget was kmix like it used to be years ago (it hasn't been true for years, but I had forgotten about that) and running the old app kmix showed two "unknown streams" for the streams created by the combined sink, presumably because kmix is too old to know about virtual streams. When it started working again, I remember I had turned up the volume for these streams, reinstalled kmix and tested, and understood what was happening. After I knew what to search for, I noticed that pavucontrol lets you set the volume for these streams too as long as you know that, in the "playback" tab, you should use the combobox at the bottom right to select "virtual streams" so as to show them.
Once you know how it works, it actually makes complete sense. It's just that when you don't, you have no way of guessing it.
